# $wpdb doesn't appear to work on page inside of a plugin

Tags: query, wpdb

I have a plugin folder foobar.

Inside this plugin I have a page called foobar.php. Inside this page I have

```
global $wpdb;
          $orderby = (!empty($_REQUEST['orderby'])) ? $_REQUEST['orderby'] : 'name'; //If no sort, default to title
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_nc_location ORDER BY " . $orderby;
          $data = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

This query works inside of my foobar.php page. However, in the same folder I have another page called process.php, and when I include the *identical* code:

```
global $wpdb;
          $orderby = (!empty($_REQUEST['orderby'])) ? $_REQUEST['orderby'] : 'name'; //If no sort, default to title
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_nc_location ORDER BY " . $orderby;
          $data = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

I get the error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in...
```

Why doesn't the global $wpdb appear to work in the other page? (process.php)?

Comment: What exactly is a "page"? Is it a file? Or do you register it as page template? Further: Admin or public facing? Because the only thing I can say from your info is that `$wpdb` is not present, so maybe the whole wp env. is not present.

Comment: I mean a php page (file).

Comment: Haha! What now: A file _or_ a page? Page = something the user sees (post type: "page"). File = A _real_ file that exists somewhere in a folder on a server and is not meant to be a "view". You could also tell how the file (if it is a file) gets loaded. This may be the problem causing the error.

Comment: No, I mean...I created an empty file, I called it process.php, and then I put in the code you see above. Otherwise do I have to call my sql using normal php code?

Comment: Which I am suspecting...would be messy.

Comment: "You could also tell how the file (if it is a file) gets loaded. This may be the problem causing the error."

Comment: You can't just plonk a standalone file into a plugin folder and expect it to operate as a WordPress file, a file being in a plugin's folder doesn't mean it will operate in a plugin context.

Comment: I plonked the code back into my foobar.php file (name of my plugin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$wpdb` object is part of WordPress, so wouldn't be loaded into a standalone PHP page as it is into a WordPress template.

You might want to look into [creating your own page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates), then you could run your database query as part of that page template.

As a side note: You are currently trusting input from the user (`$_REQUEST`) which is a Bad Thing™, as it could make you vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. The code example you give could be adapted as below to be less vulnerable:

```
global $wpdb;
$orderby = $_REQUEST['orderby'];
// Limit the values of orderby to ones we know to be safe
$acceptable_orderbys = array( 'name', 'age', 'height' );
if ( in_array( $orderby, $acceptable_orderbys ) )
    $clean_orderby = $orderby;
else
    $clean_orderby = 'name';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_nc_location ORDER BY $clean_orderby";
$data = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

I've not tested the above code, but the key thing is to check the value of `$orderby` is known to be safe before you put it into the DB query.